# Extract images from pdf in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, c#-4.0, c#-3.0

I want to extract text from pdf in my web form.
Following is the code which works perfectly but it also takes irrelevant pictures like frame picture of slide or those which has no data means blank pictures with black color or white i think it also takes the background of the picture.

```
PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(@"E:\Uni_Stuff\waleed 8th semester\DWDM\dwdm011.pdf");
        PRStream pst;
        PdfImageObject pio;
        PdfObject po;
        int n = reader.XrefSize; //number of objects in pdf document
        try
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
            {
                po = reader.GetPdfObject(i); //get the object at the index i in the objects collection
                if (po == null || !po.IsStream()) //object not found so continue
                    continue;
                pst = (PRStream)po; //cast object to stream
                PdfObject type = pst.Get(PdfName.SUBTYPE); //get the object type
                                                           //check if the object is the image type object
                if (type != null && type.ToString().Equals(PdfName.IMAGE.ToString()))
                {

                    pio = new PdfImageObject(pst); //get the image
                    byte[] imgdata = pio.GetImageAsBytes();
                    Image img = new Image();
                    img.ImageUrl = "data:image/jpeg;base64," + Convert.ToBase64String(imgdata);
                    PlaceHolder1.Controls.Add(img);
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Response.Write(ex.Message);
        }
```

Now i just want to exclude only those irrelevant pictures. I want only those pictures which has data.

Answer (score 0):

I have used this library in the passed and am sure it can do all that you need. Please try it.

http://www.winnovative-software.com/PdfImgExtractor.aspx